# Why can't PyDES output be printed without changing?

Tags: python, python-2.7, encryption, des

I have a very simple problem. Which is best explained by this sample code from the idle:

```
    from pyDes import *
>>> ciphertext = triple_des('a 16 or 24 byte password').encrypt("secret message", padmode=2)
>>> ciphertext
')\xd8\xbfFn#EY\xcbiH\xfa\x18\xb4\xf7\xa2'
>>> print ciphertext
)Ø¿Fn#EYËiHú´÷¢
```

I would appreciate it if someone could explain why this happens and how I can stop it from happening when writing this code to a txt file (without changing the decrypted output) since the `write()` function has the same effect on the text. I'm using python 2.7 on vista by the way.

Comment: `__repr__ != __str__`

Comment: Sorry, quite new to python, could you elaborate?

Comment: what, in your mind, is the correct behavior?

Comment: Just curious, are you going to use 3DES in practice?

Comment: @GregS sorry for my vagueness. your explaination shows why it happens, but my main question is how do I avoid writing the illegible version of the encrypted word to my txt file so that the decryption works right when accessed later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are in the Python shell and print some variable in this way:

```
>>> print var
```

What you get is the output of the `__str__` method of the object `var`.
Instead, when you "print" a variable in this other way:

```
>>>> var
```

What you get is the output of the `__repr__` method of the object `var`.

The difference between these two methods is that the return value of the `__repr__` function *should* be a valid python expression. Ideally you should be able to get a new object identical to `var` by simply doing a copy/paste of the output of its `__repr__` method (by the way this is not possible in every case). However the output of the `__repr__` method is intended to be used only for debugging purpose.
The `__str__` method, instead, is intended to return you a human-readable and concise representation of the object.

In your case what you get when you write `>>> ciphertext` is the "formal" representation which translate any non-printable character in its hexadecimal representation. Instead, when you use the `print` statement you get the "raw" data containing the non-printable characters as they are.

Comment: so in this case, how can i write the __reprt__ to a txt file instead of the __str__?

Comment: Why do you need that kind of output? Maybe there are better way to achieve your goal.

Comment: Well I'm making my first python programme and it's a password manager. For that, I've made one txt file where all the passwords are stored in an encrypted way and i need to write the encrypted passwords to it. however, when these passwords are written to a txt, their lengths vary, which means that they're not always a multiple of 8 bytes so the decrypt can't always decrypt them. That's why I need them to be written to the txt in a consistant format so that when i run decrypt over it, it always works. If you can think of any other way of storing the encrypted passes, i'd be grateful as well.

Comment: The correct way to store the password is the one that you are already using. Some string may look "shorter" but it is simply because of the fact that some of those characters do not have a visual representation, but they are still there.

Comment: No, when the decrypt runs over the individual words, sometimes it says that the input is not a multiple of 8bytes, while other times it works. also, it becomes a nightmare when the password gets written with a new line character in the middle because my programme assumes that the passwords are stored as account_name enc_pass. also, for some reason, it sometimes assumes a certain line to be the final line of the txt file, so even reading it in reverse makes it start reading from that certain line it the middle. It would be EXTREMELY frustrating to work with this the way it is.

Comment: When you are dealing with binary data (an encrypted string must be considered binary) you must not rely on newline or other characters as separators. In your case the best thing you can do is to convert your binary encrypted string in ascii using some encoding like base64. You can use the `base64` module for this purpose.

Comment: How about only using the binascii module. What would be the difference between using binascii.b2a_uu(data) and binascii.b2a_base64(data).

Comment: `binascii.b2a_base64` is exactly the same of `base64.b64encode`, except that the first add a newline at the end. `binascii.b2a_uu` uses uuencode. I think that bas64 is better in many cases.